General criteria of convergent of $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$
Given $f(x)$-a positive function on $\left(a,\infty\right)$. Lower bound $a$ could be chosen for every $f(x)$ so that $f(x)$ is "well-behaved" on $\left(a,\infty\right)$ (properties included : supported, no poles, no discontinuities, no oscillation)
Note: All asymtotic symbols "$\sim$" in this post is about $x\to\infty$
I observed that the following integrals are divergent:
$$\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx, \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx, \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))}dx,...$$
If $f(x)$ take the form $f(x)=x^{c_{0}}(\ln(x))^{c_1}(\ln(\ln(x)))^{c_2}...$, then we see the integrals above form a threshold for convergent of $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$, to investigate whether the integral is convergent or not, we just need to compare $c_{i}$ with $-1$ for $i=0,1,2,...$ in that order (continue if equality happens, else get decisive answer)
Let's define a sequence $L_{n}$ satisfying $L_{n+1}=\ln(e-1+L_{n}),\forall n\geq 0$ and $L_{0}=x\geq1$ . It can be proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}L_{k}=K(x)$, we still have $K(x)\sim x\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))...$ but we avoided the domain problem caused by iteration of $\ln(x)$
1. First question
Can we conclude that $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)K(x)=0$ ?
end question
Here comes non-formal maths. We already know that: $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}}\frac{x^{\varepsilon}-1}{\varepsilon}=\ln(x)$$
Using that idea: $\ln(x)\sim x^{\varepsilon}$, $\ln(\ln(x))\sim x^{\varepsilon^{2}}$,... , $e^x\sim x^{\omega}$, $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal, $\omega$ is infinity. Also, we get an expression: $K(x)\sim x^{1+\varepsilon+\varepsilon^{2}+...}$. This led me to the next question:
2. Second question
Can we always find a hyperreal number $H$ such that $f(x)\sim x^{H}$ ?
Consequently $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)K(x)=0 \iff H+1+\varepsilon+\varepsilon^{2}+...<0$
end question

Added note (I was talking about asymtotics at infinity). To be detailed, I was using the fact that as $x\to\infty$, $\ln(x)=o(x^{q})$ for all positive real $q$, $x^{\varepsilon}$ fits perfectly since $\varepsilon$ (itself a hyperreal infinitesimal) is smaller than any real positive and it can be seen through the limit of $\ln(x)$. Also, I told you it is non-formal

The answer to the first question is no, we can find a positive function $f$ such that, for all $n \in \Bbb N$,
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) l_n(x) = 0$$
where we denote $l_n(x) = x \ln(x) \ln(\ln(x)) \dots$ ($n$ times), but for which $\int f$ still diverges. (We can't simply consider the infinite product "$l_{\infty}$" because at some point the content of some $\ln$ would be negative hence ill-defined ; so I assume the closest approximation is the above)
This is done "by hand". Consider a sequence of integers $(a_m)$ "sufficiently big", as in, we need a MASSIVE space between each $a_m$ and $a_{m+1}$. Next, define $f$ by:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{l_m(x)} \; \; \text{if } x \in [a_m,a_{m+1}]$$
(if you are unhappy with this function being discontinuous, you can introduce little gaps to connect the graphs). The limit condition is satisfied, and if the gaps between the $(a_m)$ are big enough, the integral is a sum of arbitrary large terms, hence diverges. I am skipping a lot of unnecessary details to keep the answer short, feel free to write them down if you need to.

I didn't notice that, but we can fix it by consider the iteration of $\ln(e-1+x)$ instead of $\ln(x)$, the asymtotics stay the same but $l_{n}(x)$ actually converges for $x>1$, once it is legitimate to say $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)l_{\infty}(x)=0$, your argument will fail.  With this, I may edit my post as well.
